# CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting fails during StructureMap Controller Injection

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, blob, structuremap

All of a sudden I started getting the typical Structure Map error stating, "No parameterless constructor defined for this object". This is a common error and usually means that something is wrong with the object being injected. In my case, the object being injected did not change nor anything pertaining to the config, Nuget packages, etc. The object being injected simply uses Windows Azure Storage Nuget package for managing blobs. Why all of a sudden is this getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this took a bit of my time but I finally got this to work and here were the steps.

1. Commented out the code in the injected objects constructor...Error disappeared
2. Uncommented the first line of code below and received the ERROR again.

   ```
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
       CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(AppSettingName));
   ```
3. Changed the above line of code to below and everything started working.

   ```
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingName]);
   ```
4. Punched myself in the face a couple of times wondering what the devil went wrong with original code deployed in Azure is working!

Comment: The source of your problem lies this: [your constructors do too much](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). As a general rule of thumb, only read the application's configuration during the startup phase of your application; in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).